# Probability of occurring of two dependent events happening in sequence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There is a sports gun whose probability of working is $0.8$, i.e. it functions $80\%$ of the time I operate it. The probability that it hits the target accurately when i use it is $0.6$, i.e. $60\%$ of the time the gun hits the target accurately.  0.8 is the serviceability of the gun, the gun is serviceable for firing. 0.6 is the probability that i as a shooter hit the target accurately. i can hit target accurately only 6 out of 10 times.

1. What is the probability that the gun when fired hits the target, on any given day if I use the gun ?
2. I understood that functioning of gun and target accurately being hit are dependent events. Because if the gun is not functioning, I can’t hit the target. Also I can’t change the sequence of events. Due to these reasons I assumed they are dependent events, is my assumption correct? Are they dependent events?
3. Is the data adequate to calculate probability of hitting the target if I pick up the gun any day?

Comment: This is not clear.  What does the $.6$ mean?  You say it's the probability that you hit the target, but is that what you meant?  Or did you mean "it's the probability that you hit the target, given that it functions properly."?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: i added more details. 0.6 is probability that i shoot the target accurately. 6 out of 10 attempts i hit the target accurately. Once the gun functions properly, this is my accuracy probability.

Comment: When you say "the probability that the gun when fired hits the target," does "fired" mean "operated" or "works". I find that when posing questions like these, it is clearer when you don't use many synonyms, because then it's not clear which of "working", "fires", "operates", "use", "serviceable", etc., are the same.

Comment: What you are writing is contradictory.  "0.6 is probability that i shoot the target accurately. 6 out of 10 attempts i hit the target accurately." and "Once the gun functions properly, this is my accuracy probability" mean different things.

Comment: @Joe Sorry for confusion. 0.8 is probability of gun operating i.e. I am able to press the trigger. Rest of the 0.2 is that  I am unable to press the trigger itself, irrespective at this stage if don't know if I fire, I may or may not hit the target. When I am able to press trigger, out of 10 times I fire, 6 times I hit the target.

Comment: @Lulu I am sorry if I am not clear. 10 times I attempt to press the trigger, only 8 times I can press the trigger, other 2 times due to gun mechanical issues, I cannot press the trigger itself. 
Once I am able to press the trigger, I fire the gun 10 times, 6 times I can hit the target. 
Now, on a given day, if I pick up my gun and fire, what is probability that I fire the gun and i hit the target accurately.

Comment: Ok!  So the $.6$ is a conditional probability.  If $W$ denotes the event "the gun is working" and $H$ denotes the event "you hit your target"  we have $.6=P(H\,|\,W)$.  It should be easy for you to finish from here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the event "The gun shoots and hits the target" and "The gun is working, i.e. it shoots" are dependent. We can actually prove that this is the case if we can show that
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{ The gun shoots and hits the target}) \neq \mathbb{P}(\text{ The gun shoots and hits the target} \ | \ \text{ The gun is working }).$$
In fact we know that the second probability is $0.6$ by the assumptions (as clarified in the comments). The first probability can be rewritten as
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{ The gun shoots and hits the target} \ | \ \text{ The gun is working }) \mathbb{P}(\text{ The gun is working }),$$
since on the envent "The gun is not working" the probability of hitting the target is zero. You know both terms in this product, so a multiplication will answer everything.